# Video like in Spotlight?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I use Quicklook to preview videos.
However, instead of showing the preview with a big "Play" button in the middle of the preview panel, my videos are display with a small navigation bar on the bottom.

Does anybody know how to make Video in a QL look like the one in Spotlight (big button, no navigation) ?

Or just how to modify the standard navigation ?

Comment: It's not clear this is a programming question. Would you clarify?

Comment: How does your video display in the Finder when you press space with the video file selected?

Comment: @noa off course this is a coding question, and I was not talking about finder but spotlight

Answer (score 0):

Try using [QLPreviewView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Quartz/Reference/QLPreviewView_Class/) instead of QLPreviewPanel.